# Windows 8: 20 gig of data file went missing

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, data-recovery

Last day, my 400 Gb hdd data drive (D: DATA) was fully red w/ 40 Gig of free space available. Then I went to restart it and poof! 60 Gig free space available. What the?! It appears that a 20 Gig of files went missing!

I tried to do recovery and nothing shows up to be missing.

Any help, or clarification to this matter is highly appreciated. :)

Comment: did it update?  maybe there were a bunch of old update files that suddenly got deleted.  20Gb seems like a lot, but I know that updates installers don't always get deleted correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you tried to run recovery and found nothing missing and your hard drive is healthy, you can check this with crystal disk info. Then windows was misreporting your free space, or cleared up some temp files on restart. I have had similar problems when my hard drive is close to full.

Comment: whooo, at least I have known that this is not an unexpected case. thanks!